# Possibility of getOrElseReturn in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, lambda, java-8

I often have a problem with `Optional` and similar classes `Option`, `Try`, `Either` from [VAVR](https://github.com/vavr-io/vavr) for example.

Let's say I have some `Optional`, and if it's empty I want to immediately return from a method (without exception, since my method is returning `Optional` aswell, so `getOrElseThrow` is out of the picture) and if it's present I want to further process it.

```java
public Optional<Integer> converter() {
  Optional<String> opt = getSomething();

  if(!opt.isPresent())
    return Optional.empty();

  String value = opt.get();  
  // some manipulations on value, such as map and flatMap would cause a huge mess
  return Integer.parseInt(value);  
}
```

I just need to return immediately in case value is empty, I can't do chain of `map` and `flatMap`. The whole pain is doing `.get()`. Something like `getOrElseThrow`, but with `return` instead of `throw` would be fantastic - `getOrElseReturn`. Obviously not possible in Java, so I thought about trying this in Kotlin.

```kotlin
fun safeOptional(): Optional<Int> {
    val extracted = Optional.of("123")
            .getOrElseReturn { return Optional.empty() }

    val modified = extracted.toInt() * 2

    return Optional.of(modified)
}

private inline fun <T> Optional<T>.getOrElseReturn(block: (Optional<T>) -> T): T {
    return if (!this.isPresent)
        block(this)
    else
        this.get()
}
```

Much to my surprise it actually does what I want. If I change the `Optional.of("123")` to `Optional.empty()` it immediately returns from a method. I don't understand how it compiles though.

My method needs a `block: (Optional<T>) -> T`, otherwise it wouldn't compile. So in my case I have `Optional<String>` and I need to pass a `block: (Optional<String>) -> String`, but hey - the block that I have is nowhere close to this and it still compiles, how?

When I extract the block to variable it becomes `val block: (Optional<String>) -> Nothing` (I guess `return` statement is `Nothing`) and it still compiles, surprising me even more.

btw I know this code is not strictly what I want - someone can pass another block without non-local return to the method, but I don't think there is another way

Comment: In the Java code, why can't you use `return getSomething().map(Integer::parseInt)`?

Comment: There’s so much text in the question, the real question seems to be lost.

Answer (score 5):

Extract the second part of your method into another private method and call `getSomething().map(this::otherPrivateMethod)`

It will not be invoked if no value is present in `getSomething()`

Basically,

```
public Optional<Integer> converter() {
    return getSomething().map(this::privateConverter); 
}

private Integer privateConverter(Integer integer) {
    // some manipulations on value, such as map and flatMap would cause a huge mess
    return Integer.parseInt(value);  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Answering the Kotlin part:

```
fun safeOptional(): Optional<Int> {
    val extracted = Optional.of("123")
            .getOrElseReturn { return Optional.empty() } 
    .......
}
```

The return here is not return from a lambda, but rather a return from function `safeOptional` so therefore lambda doesn't return anything (it returns [Nothing](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-nothing.html)). Lambda returning Nothing can be passed as lambda returning anything.

To get a compile error, you should return from lambda instead:

```
val extracted = Optional.of("123")
    .getOrElseReturn { return@getOrElseReturn Optional.empty() }
```

Generally, Optional are not needed in Kotlin. You should use nullable types instead. You would combine them with nullsafe operators (e.g. the Elvis operator -- `?:`:

```
fun nullsafe(x: String?): Optional<Int> {
    val extracted = x ?: return Optional.empty()
    val modified = extracted.toInt() * 2

    return Optional.of(modified)
}

nullsafe("2") // => Optional[4]
nullsafe(null) // => Optional.empty
```